# To find interfaces

Tags: python, regex

I am not good at RegEx. I need help with identifying the first word of the line which starts with word Fast/Giga. RegEx I tried `"^\s*(?=Fast|Giga).\w+"`, but it's not adding from '/', need full name like "`GigabitEthernet2/47`" which matches the "up" and "down" separately.

```
GigabitEthernet2/47 (this should belong to up)
GigabitEthernet2/48 (this should belong to down)
FastEthernet3/1 (this should belong to down)
FastEthernet3/2 (this should belong to down)
FastEthernet3/3 (this should belong to down)
```

And also need RegEx for this line alone

```
"Last input 00:00:09, output 00:00:00, output hang never"
```

Need three RegEx for input, output, and output hang. Whichever the thing
next to (input, output, and output hang) should display only that.

```
00:00:09 (this should belong to input)
00:00:00 (this should belong to output)
never    (this should belong to output hang)

interface GigabitEthernet6/48
 description ***connected to Panel***
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet7/1
!
GigabitEthernet2/47 is up, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is 0023.0460.5a4e (bia 0023.0460.5a4e)
  Last input 00:00:09, output 00:00:00, output hang never
GigabitEthernet2/48 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is 0023.0460.5a4f (bia 0023.0460.5a4f)
  Last input 42w6d, output 42w6d, output hang never
FastEthernet3/1 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Hardware is Fast Ethernet Port, address is 0022.906f.4040 (bia 0022.906f.4040)
   Last input 00:00:58, output 00:00:00, output hang never
FastEthernet3/2 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Hardware is Fast Ethernet Port, address is 0022.906f.4041 (bia 0022.906f.4041)
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
FastEthernet3/3 is administratively down, line protocol is down (disabled)
  Hardware is Fast Ethernet Port, address is 0022.906f.4042 (bia 0022.906f.4042)
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
TenGigabitEthernet4/6 is down, line protocol is down (inactive)
  Hardware is Ten Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is 843d.c632.a74d (bia 843d.c632.a74d)
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will capture the name that you require:

```
(^(?:Giga|Fast)\S+)
```

Up and down match now separated (the reason they were initially grouped together was to ensure that the `up` and `down` were only matched if the line began with either `Giga` or `Fast`):

```
(?:.*?)(up|down)(?:.*?)(up|down)
```

**Explanation**

Assert start of line and a non-capturing group to match either Giga or Fast (since the whole match is included in the outer capturing group), followed by one of more non-whitespace characters:

```
(^(?:Giga|Fast)\S+)
```

Non-greedy non-capturing group to match everything leading up to either up or down (repeated twice to meet your needs):

```
(?:.*?)(up|down)(?:.*?)(up|down)
```

The following will capture the input, output and output hang:

```
(?:(?<=input )|(?<=output )(?:hang )?)(.*?)(?:\,|$)
```

**Explanation**

Non-capturing group of the various options, either input or output (with an optional hang), terminating the match if a comma `,` or the end of the line is reached.

Comment: can i have separate regex for up, down, input, output & output hang. ? I am not looking for combined one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was able to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

For the first Regex you need, you have the first part down. Now you just need to match the `/` and the numbers that follow it.

```
^\s*(?=Fast|Giga).\w+/\d+
```

First, I added a `/` to match the slash character. Then, I added `\d+`. The `\d` matches digit characters, also known as numbers. The `+` modifies the `\d` symbol, making it match at least one digit character.

EDIT: To match if it is down, use

```
(^\s*(?=Fast|Giga).\w+/\d+) is down
```

And for up, use

```
(^\s*(?=Fast|Giga).\w+/\d+) is up
```

Comment: i need whichever it also contain the word either "up" or "down". so that i can match which one is down and up.

Comment: sorry its not working. I need only the GigabitEthernet2/47 which contains the word 'up' same for 'down' as well.

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu See my new edit. I put the name part in parentheses, meaning it will be captured. Then, you have to only use the part that is captured.

Comment: r"(^\s*(?=Fast|Giga).\w+/\d+) is down" this is python regex i am using, it showing entire line.

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu Once you get a match object, get the group with group(), which should only contain the group name. If you cannot figure this out, please include your code in your post.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will figure that out. Let me put some work for my brain.